# Eclipse -- Long Shot Debugging Request -- Possible to put a watch on every variable

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Need to figure out where a key string is being set.

I want to tell Eclipse to stop, as if on a breakpoint, as soon as a variable is set to something, say "key_value_here"?

This isn't possible is it?
:P

Comment: Where does this key value end up? Set a watch on that, and just follow it backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear, but if i understand what you mean it is possible:
If this is a field in a class, set the breakpoint on its declaration. the right click on the breakpoint will allow you to edit breakpoint properties. there you can choose access or modification break.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping it would be something of "any variable of this type with this value X".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if eclipse offers a "conditional watch point". If it does, that solves your problem nicely. If not, you can set a [conditional breakpoint](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F) on each line that assigns the variable in question.